# is it possible to use a circuit to reliably measure when a motor has 'stalled'

Tags: power, motor

ive been fixing my electric garage door opener and it got me thinkin...

the motor turns a geared chain that moves the door up and down. there is a small mechanical device attached to the mechanism that appears to use a optical sensor/rotating cup that measures RPM's and is there to sense if the motor has stopped turning. I believe this is a safety system.  I say this because there is another mechanical contraption that creates/breaks simple connection based on a turning screw with 2 end 'stop's that you can adjust to move them in or out and this is what tells the motor how much 'travel' to have.

my question is .. cant you replace this mechanical junk with a circuit that would sense when the current draw of teh motor spikes (and thus assume that the door is fully open or closed) and use this condition to stop sending pwr to the motor ?

oops.. i probably should know if its a dc or ac motor but i dont.

Comment: You mean like a shunt resistor and a differential amplifier?

Comment: This could be a potentially good question if you came back and cleaned it up a bit. Stuff like "i probably should know"... find out ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is technically possible. In fact, my garage door opener will reverse if the door hits an obstacle. That is detected by the motor current increasing. There's also an encoder to measure the travel so the motion does not depend on the obstacle detector system or electric eye. I have not traced the circuit out, but I would expect something like a small current transformer or shunt resistor to roughly measure the motor current. There is an adjustment to trim the sensitivity so it does not reverse because of slight binding, and does not exert too much pressure (and a procedure to set the current limit). It would be a lot harder on the drive since it actually has to impact and begin to stall the motor to work.

This is a safety critical subsystem, and I would not suggest fiddling with it unless you really are willing to accept all the risk and know what exactly you are doing (and if you have to ask, you don't).

Every year people (mostly young children) are severely injured or [killed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8885959) by garage doors, some of which have had the safety systems bypassed by amateur installers. Here's an example of a bypassed electric eye safety system. I've seen photos of them mounted on the ceiling too. I imagine it's grounds for jail time if someone gets injured.

[image]

> In the United States, at least 85 children have had permanent brain injury or have died since 1974 as a result of accidents involving automatic door openers.